# Generalize this notation for an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

I have

> $$
> \frac{dN(t)}{dt}=a(t)N(t) \tag 1
> $$
> where $N(0)=N_0 $ (constant).

*Question 1:*
From the information in $(1)$ I assume I have the functions $a, N:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$? And $N_0\in \mathbb R$? Is that correct?

Suppose I now want to generalize the notation in $(1)$ by replacing the right hand side with a function $f$.

*Question 2:*
Does this mean I should write
$$
\frac{d N(t)}{dt}=f(t) \tag 2
$$
where $N, f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ ?

Or maybe

$$
\frac{dN(t)}{dt}=f(a(t),N(t)) \tag 3
$$
where $f:\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$?

Or maybe

$$
\frac{dN(t)}{dt}=f(t,a(t),N(t)) \tag 4
$$
where $f:\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $t \in \mathbb R$?

$\times$ is the Cartesian product.

Which one is correct? Thanks!

Comment: There are no correct/incorrect options. What you have are more and more general cases, but it all depends on the particular problem to solve. Just as if you were asking "what is correct among $z=f(x)$ and $z=f(x,y)$ ? Anyway, $f(t,a(t),N(t))$ can be written $f(t,N(t))$.

Comment: The most general form of a first order ODE is probably $f(t,N(t),N'(t))=0$.

Answer (score -1):

An explicit first order ODE has the following form (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#General_definition))
$$
\frac{dN(t)}{dt} = f(t, N(t)).
$$

The form (2) is too narrow, since does not allow dependence on $N(t)$ in the right hand side. Form (3) does not allow dependence on raw $t$, and the form (4) has extra $a(t)$ which may be easily built in the definition of $f(t, N)$ itself.

Few examples:

1. $\frac{dN(t)}{dt} = g(t)$ is a special case of $f(t, N) = g(t)$
2. $\frac{dN(t)}{dt} = a(t) N(t)$ is a special case of $f(t, N) = a(t) N$
3. $\frac{dN(t)}{dt} = \frac{a(t)}{N(t) + t}$ is a special case of $f(t, N) = \frac{a(t)}{N + t}$

Comment: No, one can take $f(t) = g(t, N(t))$, this is equivalent.

Comment: $a(t)$ is known a-priori, while $N(t)$ is obtained from solving the equation. This is why definition of $f(t)$ may contain $a(t)$ but can not contain $N(t)$

Comment: Even if I understand what you mean, formally there is no way to distinguish these expressions. I can say: let $N$ be the solution of $N'(t) = f(t)$ with $f(t) = g(t,N(t))$. Rigorously, one should say explicitly that one doesn't want the $f(t)$ to depend on $N$.